# A question about a Bianchi identity satisfied by Ricci curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

This is an excerpt from Fefferman's paper on the Ambient metric:

> The Ricci curvature of $\tilde{g}$ satisfies the Bianchi identity $\tilde{g}^{JK}\nabla_I\tilde{R}_{JK}=2\tilde{g}^{JK}\nabla_J\tilde{R}_{IK}$

The Bianchi identity that I'm aware of says that $\nabla_I R_{JK}+\nabla_J R_{KI}+\nabla_K R_{IJ}=0$. Here $R$ stands for the curvature tensor, and not the Ricci tensor as mentioned in the statement. Are the two related? What Bianchi identity is Fefferman talking about? Thanks!

Comment: So is $R$ curvature & $\tilde{R}$ Ricci?

Comment: @J.G.- Yes that is correct

Comment: To me, "curvature tensor" usually means the Riemann tensor of rank $4$, or the Ricci tensor of rank $2$ obtained by contacting two of Riemann's indices. So what do you mean by $R$, besides that?

Comment: @J.G.- By $\nabla_I R_{JK}$, I mean the following: $\nabla_I R(J,K) W$ for an arbitrary vector $W$. Here by $I,J,K$, we mean the $i, j ,k$th unit coordinate vectors

Comment: It looks like the [contracted Bianchi identities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contracted_Bianchi_identities).